# state value set to initial state after using uselazyQuery in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo

When I tried to set `signType12` on button click then it firstly set the correct value after that it calls an API via useEffect using useLazyQuery then `signType12` gives `null` as initial state.

Below are the code...

```
const [getOrder] = useLazyQuery(GET_BUSINESS_LIFE_ORDER, {
fetchPolicy: "no-cache",
onError: useCallback((err: any) => {
  apiErrorHandler(err);
  setIsTransLoading(false);
}, []),
onCompleted: useCallback(({ getBusinessLifeOrder }: any) => {
  setLifeOrder(getBusinessLifeOrder);
  setLoading(false);
  console.log(signType12, "sign12");
  if (getBusinessLifeOrder.signatureId) {
    getOrderSignatureInfo({
      variables: {
        id: orderId,
      },
    });
  } else if (signType12 != null) {
    companySignDoc({
      variables: {
        orderId: orderId,
        deliveryMethod:
          signType12 == "url" ? "URL" : signType12 == "email" ? "EMAIL" : null,
        userType: "LEGALREPRESENTATIVE",
        signer1: {
          name: getBusinessLifeOrder.contactInfo.name,
          email: getBusinessLifeOrder.contactInfo.email,
        },
      },
    });
  }
  // setIsTransLoading(false);
}, []), });

useEffect(() => {
if (signType12) {
  console.log(signType12, “sign12”);
  // setIsTransLoading(true);
  getOrder({ variables: { id: orderId } });
}}, [signType12]);
```

The return function is

```
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setSignType12('url')
          }}>
          Assinar agora
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setSignType12('email')
          }}>
          Enviar documento por email
        </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing this issue because this is how useCallback() works in react.

Let's understand:

```
useCallback(someFunction, []) 
// someFunction will be initialized only once.
// and if you're using any state inside it. 
// state value will be same, that was passed during initialization
```

Solution:

```
useCallback(someFunction, [state]) // state which you want to use
```